# How can I use from ismember

Tags: matlab, matrix, extract

Assuming

```
A=[32512199.30 5401000.29  347.33  
32512199.69 5401000.45  347.39    
32512199.67 5401001.32  353.58    
32512199.96 5401001.50  346.99    
32512196.71 5401001.69  346.62    ]
```

and

```
 B=[32512199.30 5401000.29  347.33  
    32512199.69 5401000.45  347.39     
    32512199.67 5401001.32  347.00     
    32512198.85 5401000.91  347.25     
    32512196.71 5401001.69  346.87     ]
```

I want using ismember extract the rows that have same X and Y and different Z. X is first column, Y is the second and Z is third.
in A and B I want extract from A `32512199.67 5401001.32  353.58` and `32512196.71 5401001.69  346.62` OR from B   `32512199.67 5401001.32  347.00` and `32512196.71 5401001.69  346.87`
How can I do it?

Comment: Tell us what have you tried.

Comment: ex=find(ismember(A(:,[1,2]),B(:,[1,2]),'rows'));
but it isn't answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find the row indices of desired match using `ismember` and `find`. Then extract those rows from `A/B` to `XA/XB`

```
row_idx = find ( ismember( ismember(A,B), [1 1 0], 'rows') )

XA = A(row_idx,:)
XB = B(row_idx,:)
```

Output:

```
row_idx =

   3
   5

XA =

   3.2512e+07   5.4010e+06   3.5358e+02
   3.2512e+07   5.4010e+06   3.4662e+02

XB =

   3.2512e+07   5.4010e+06   3.4700e+02
   3.2512e+07   5.4010e+06   3.4687e+02
```

Comment: This algorithm answer here but when I run to my data don't answer.
can you help me? tnx.

Comment: @ahmadhosseini Do you mean to say you don't get output display? If yes, just do `disp(XA)` etc.. or remove semicolon at the end of a line. Updated my ans. I thought printing matrix value was very straight forward.

Comment: I know, I mean that the answer is false :(

Comment: It's a logical error not syntax.
I run in another data and don't answer.

Comment: ans is false? It gives proper output on your sample data as demonstrated. Please provide the data where you don't get desired answer. otherwise I have no clue how to check.

Comment: A is here: [link](http://www.mediafire.com/view/d28427662cz57aq/A.txt)
and B is here: [link](http://www.mediafire.com/view/5dole0i3lxvf5of/B.txt).
I get XA and XB with 34 rows but they have not same X and Y.

Answer (score 1):

```
inds = find(~ismember(A, B, 'rows'));
new_inds = find(ismember(A(inds, 1:2), B(:, 1:2), 'rows'));
inds(new_inds)
```

Comment: Thank U.
but it is important for me that extract the rows that have different Z.